# Resize a view when another is hidden

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, nslayoutconstraint

I have two views on the iPhone screen, one above the other (mediaControls above deviceWebView). When I hide the top view I want the bottom view to take up the entire screen, and when I reveal the top view I want the bottom view to resize again to be below the top view. It seems very simple but I am having trouble with it.
I've tried only hiding the view as well as adjusting the layout constraints as I show below.

Heres my code:

```
-(void)hideVideoButtons{
    self.mediaControls.hidden = YES;
    [self.view removeConstraint:self.deviceLayoutConstraint];
    [self.deviceWebView setNeedsDisplay];
}
-(void)showVideoButtons{
    self.mediaControls.hidden=NO;
    self.deviceLayoutConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.deviceWebView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mediaControls attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:self.deviceLayoutConstraint];
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the UIView animateWithDuration: animations: method? You can animate the UIView(s) to whatever location you'd like, you can resize them, and much more.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
   // moving the device web view 
   self.deviceWebView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xVar, yVar);
   // moving the other view
   otherView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(xVar, yVar);
}];
```

the xVar and yVar are not variables being set. They are just showing the usage of the method. You'd replace them with the x and y locations of the screen you are wanting to move the x and y of the view to. I'm not fully sure if this is what you're looking for, but it seems you are looking for a way to animate the views, so here's a suggestion :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I hesitate to use x and y coords because that won't work for any size screen (i.e iPhone 4 and iPhone 5)